# Segmentation fault when writing to a file

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, file-writing

UPDATED CODE FULLY FUNCTIONAL***

I'm new to C/C++ and I wrote a piece of code that would count the number of times the program has run by writing 'count' to a file each time. Except I'm getting a seg fault error when I try to run it. Anyone can tell me why ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    printf("LINE 13 CLEAR");
    fp = fopen("MyPlayground.rtf", "r");
    int value;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &value);
    printf("Value is %d", value);
    //printf("LINE 14 CLEAR");
    if(fp== NULL)
    {
        printf("LINE 17 CLEAR");
        if(fopen("MyPlayground.rtf", "w")==NULL)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        //fprintf(fp,"%d",0);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
    //printf("LINE 25 CLEAR");
    fp = fopen("MyPlayground.rtf", "w");
    //printf("LINE 30 CLEAR");
    fprintf(fp,"%d",++value);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

EDIT: The program runs until "printf("LINE 17 CLEAR");" and after that it gives me an 'EXC-BAD-ACCESS' error in the following line.

EDIT1: Fixed fixed the two different paths

EDIT2: Added error check for second `fopen(...)` statement.

Also, feel free to comment on any style errors and things I should/should not do. Thanks.

Comment: Check that all of your fopen and fscanf calls worked by examining their return values.

Comment: Check `/Desktop/hw3/` directory has write permission.

Comment: Spend 30 minutes to learn your system's debugger and save days and hours of writing debug statements for the rest of your life. You really only need to know how to set and clear breakpoints, step into functions and print variables...

Comment: @Shravan40 It does.

Comment: BTW, there is no language "C/C++", they are two different languages.  For example, C++ has `std::ifstream`, `std::fstream` and `std::string` for reading text from files, the C language doesn't.  The C language does not support overloading of functions.

Comment: Why do you need the `counter` variable?  You could increment the `value` variable as: `++value`.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statement caused the segmentation fault?

Comment: The `fscanf` returns the number of items scanned.  Assign the result to a variable and check if the correct number of variables were read.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews see my edit

Comment: The two paths are different.  One uses `/Desktop`, the other has `/Desktop/hw3`.  Are they to be the same?  Do you have write (permission) to `/Desktop`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews and good point on the '++value'. I don't know why I didn't just do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet it only happens a first time you run it. The reason why is line 11:

11       fprintf(fp, 0);

You are basically passing fprintf a null pointer. What you probably meant to do was this:

11       fprintf(fp, "0");

Here is how I figured it out. I compiled it with debug info and ran it using debugger... lldb, to be precise:

(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0xacaaf, 0x00007fff90f4dcf6 libsystem_c.dylib`__vfprintf + 327, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff90f4dcf6 libsystem_c.dylib`__vfprintf + 327

```
frame #1: 0x00007fff90f762e7 libsystem_c.dylib`__v2printf + 471

frame #2: 0x00007fff90f766bc libsystem_c.dylib`__xvprintf + 633

frame #3: 0x00007fff90f4db36 libsystem_c.dylib`vfprintf_l + 54

frame #4: 0x00007fff90f4669b libsystem_c.dylib`fprintf + 186

frame #5: 0x0000000100000e9d test.out`main(argc=1,
```

argv=0x00007fff5fbffc60) + 109 at test.c:11
    frame #6: 0x00007fff8f9c95fd libdyld.dylib`start + 1

...if you look at frame 5, you will see the offending line of code.

Comment: fprintf is not being passed a null pointer. If `fp = fopen("/Desktop/hw3/hw3/MyPlayground.txt", "w");` does not find a file with that name in that directory it just creates one. So I don't see why it would be null after that statement.

Comment: @MarcoNeves he's not saying `fp` is null, he meant the second parameter.

Comment: Oh I see, so doing `fprintf(fp, "%d", 0);` would technically fix it, right ?

Comment: @MarcoNeves I don't see this error in the question. Why did you remove it in an edit, since it's most likely the problem.

Comment: @MarcoNeves "if fopen(...) does not find a file with that name in that directory it just creates one" predicated on fopen() succeeding. Even if you have every reason to believe it will succeed, you should still check the return value to make sure it is not NULL. It may fail because the directory does not exist, the permissions are not right...

Comment: @Barmar I didn't remove it, I added it. I initially had it as `fprintf(fp,0);`

Comment: @MarcoNeves That's the problem, and you removed it. Now this answer makes no sense, because it's referring to the original version of the question.

Comment: @Barmar ... that was not the problem. Changing it did not fix it, though I realize how I initially had it was wrong. In other words, before and after I am still getting the same error at the same line. Does that make sense ?

Comment: @MarcoNeves Add an error check for the second `fopen()`.

Comment: @MarcoNeves so your program had more than one bug. It happens all the time. Point is, this answer identified one of them, then you changed the question.

Comment: @MarkRansom Noted that this answer did somewhat address my question, but it did not fix the original problem. I still get a seg fault error even though he did point out a bug that I was not aware of. I never changed the question. I gave +1 for point out the bug though

Comment: @Barmar I added an error check. See edit and let me know what you think. The error still persists tho. It's really frustrating

Comment: @VirtuallyReal I added the error check and double checked my permissions and I have both read and write permissions.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. I checked if the return value was null, but if it is wouldn't it print the error message ? It's not even doing that. It simply says EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: If `fopen()` fails, you you should exit the program. Otherwise, you still execute `fprintf(fp, "%d", 0);` with the null `fp`.

Comment: Run the program in a debugger so you can single-step it and examine the variables.

Comment: @MarcoNeves OK, you had **3** bugs. You're not assigning the result of the second `fopen` to `fp`.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? I took all the suggested answers and I finally got it to work correctly. Thanks for all the help, I'll update my code now.